# Launch script at the end of the run in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

For a specific case, I need all PyCharm projects to run a given script at the end of each run.

In the Run/Debug configurations, there is an option to run a script before launch. Is there a similar option to run a script once the run is over?

If it does not exist (as I suspect), is there another trick I could use, maybe with a zsh alias or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the plugin [Multirun](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7248-multirun) on any JetBrains IDE. Using that just create a configuration for your main script and another one for the end-script. After that just create a Multirun configuration that calls both of your scripts.